# Boolean value is not changing in another method java

Tags: java, android

I have defined boolean hasCoverage to true. When it calls the next method where the actual code makes hasCoverage value to false or true based on the selected data. The things is the value which I have set initially, thats only taking. 
Here is my code:

```
boolean hasCoverage = true;

private void checkCoverage() {
    try {
        JSONObject[] restaurants_arr = null;
        try {
            if (response != null) {
                JSONArray restaurants = response.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                // if restaurants deliver to that area
                if (restaurants.length() > 0) {
                    restaurants_arr = new JSONObject[restaurants.length()];
                    int has_coverage = 1; // assume coverage is there..

                    for (int j = 0; j < Utils.cart_restaurants.size(); j++) {
                        RestaurantModel restaurant = Utils.cart_restaurants.get(j);
                        String restaurantCartID = restaurant.getId();
                        boolean found = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                            restaurants_arr[i] = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
                            String restaurantID = restaurants_arr[i].get("restaurant_id").toString();
                            if (restaurantCartID.equals(restaurantID)) {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }  //end of inner for
                        if (found == false) {
                            Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "There is no coverage for the Selected Area ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            hasCoverage = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } //end of outer for
                } //end of if
                else { //if restaurants don't deliver to that area
                    Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "There is no coverage for the Selected Area ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hasCoverage = false;
                }
            } // end of if response != null
        } // end of try
        catch (Exception ex) {
            GSLogger.e(ex);
            showError();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have defined. Based on the area coverage boolean value is changing. Now, I want to pass the value which i received here in this method to the next method. 
Here is the code:

```
checkout_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        city_id = addressObj.getCity().getId();
        if (Utils.isLoggedIn) {
            checkCoverage();
            if (hasCoverage) { // hasCoverage takes initialized value which is difened at the beginning
                processOrder();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this, "There is no coverage for the Selected Area ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @QBrute if(hasCoverage) is taking only true value. It is not changing. checkCoverage() changes the initial value from true to false based on the user selection. The false is not setting to if(hasCoverage) function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - Please change your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Debugger should be able to help you. Put breakpoints in your code and check the execution flow. You might get the answer. :)

Comment: @Jacky Have you tried debugging your code? I'm guessing it always finds a restaurant so none of the branches where `hasCoverage` is set to `false` apply.

Comment: @AndréStannek Yes I did. hasCoverage is set to false under checkCoverage(). Still the if(hasCoverage) is taking true which is initialized value. The value is not passing to the next method

Comment: @Jacky I can't see the problem from the code you are showing. If `hasCoverage` is a field in the same class, this should work. You could look for accidental hiding with local variables of the same name but my suggestion would be a refactoring: Scrap the field and make `checkCoverage()` return a boolean directly. From what you've showed us, this would be the better design imho.

Comment: @AndréStannek Thanks a lot. Followed your instructions. Its working now.